# Ubuntu Touch import Contacts

Tags: ubuntu-touch, contacts

How to import contacts in Ubuntu Touch (current release i.e. installed on 17. september)?
The manage-address-books.py mentioned in the release notes seems not to exist anymore (at least I did not manage to find it).

Is there a simple way to import vCards using syncevolution or does a DBus service exist for creating/importing contacts?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use syncevolution.  This is how I imported my Google contacts:

```
adb shell sudo -u phablet -i syncevolution --configure --sync-property "username=email@gmail.com" --sync-property "password=XXXXXXX" Google_Contacts
adb shell sudo -u phablet -i syncevolution --sync one-way-from-server Google_Contacts addressbook
```

That second line will import 50 contacts at a time.  Repeat to get more.