# bq aquaris e4.5 ubuntu many problems

Tags: ubuntu-touch, icons, contacts, bq

This morning I received the phone (bq ubuntu edition) and arrived several problems: after updates that required me to have disappeared icons of some applications and and left with the caption, the second most serious problem and that I can not in any way to import my contacts, not I found no setting about but to place them one by one by hand but you can? thanks for any help

Comment: Please state one question per problem and try being a bit more descriptive. For importing contacts you can use syncevolution after installing the terminal application https://askubuntu.com/questions/346861/ubuntu-touch-import-contacts. You can also import with syncevolution from vcards. This might be command line, but it really is only a oneliner.

Comment: Missing icons might be https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity8/+bug/1430828

Answer (score 0):

For the contacts: If you are using google account to store your contacts then navigate to **System Settings>Accounts>Google** and there is a setting to synchronize contacts. When you tick this setting you have to wait some time for it to sync.

Answer (score 0):

Another way for importing contacts, without using the commandline:

Export them as .vcf file from your "old" phone. Install "dekko" mail client on your ubuntu phone and configure it to use one of your mail accounts somewhere (dekko supports imap, pop3 etc.) 
Send (from any computer) an email with the .vcf file attached to that (your) account. "Receive" / get / open that mail using "dekko" on your ubuntu phone. Tap on the attached file. You will be asked to import it into your "contacts". 
Worked perfect for me. If you have an IPhone, there are multiple apps in Apple's app store which are capable to export your contacts as one .vcf file.

Further info:
[Ubuntu Touch/Phone sim card contacts import](https://askubuntu.com/questions/598479/ubuntu-touch-phone-sim-card-contacts-import/600641#600641)
or do a search for yourself, i've seen this issue several times on askubuntu.com.

kind regards